# Insomnia generated request code doesn't work

Tags: node.js, cookies, request, fetch, insomnia

I'm trying to send a login request to a server that uses cookies. The request works perfectly in Insomnia client. My request looks like this:

```
POST: https://website.com/...
Headers:
* accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
* accept-language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,hr;q=0.5
* content-type: application/json
* [custom-header-field]: jk#Bea201
Body is json:
{ "email": "...", "password": "..." }
```

When I send the request it works. Returns a 200 with response data + set-cookie headers.
However, the code generated by insomnia doesn't work. Here it is :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let url = '...';

let options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,hr;q=0.5',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'custom-field-...': 'jk#Bea201'
  },
  body: '{"email":"...","password":"..."}'
};

fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
```

For some reason, running this code makes my node program hang, no error message. It **only** works when I add the cookies that I receive from the Insomnia request into the headers. But to my understanding, there is no way of me knowing in advance what those cookies are.
I have even tried using [fetch-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-cookie), and it gives the same result. Doing it with curl gives me the following error:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;[website];com&#47;authentication&#47;login" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;44c01160&#46;1645662994&#46;95d786
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is this because of CORS?